# What to use for real-time log aggregation and querying?

Tags: logging, real-time, hbase

I'm searching for tool/database/solution that can help me with aggregating real-time logs and can query them also in real-time.
Basic requirement is ability to deliver results as soon as possible, keeping in mind, that there might be many of events to query (possibly billions), but logs would have many 'columns' and each query would set some conditions on those columns, so final result will be some kind of aggregation, or only small subset of rows would be returned.

Right now I was looking at HDFS+HBase which seems like a good solution. Are there any alternatives? Can you recommend anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check Flume: https://github.com/cloudera/flume/wiki .

Comment: Flume might help with writing logs to HDFS, but doesn't solve the issue of querying this data.

Comment: @Wojtek: based on the question I assumed Hadoop HDFS + HBase will be used for collating/querying data.

Comment: Probably, I'm still looking for alternatives. But Flume (+HBase sink) + HBase + HDFS seems to be good way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at [calamaris](http://cord.de/tools/squid/calamaris/). In the commercial world there's [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/).

Comment: This is nice, but I'm also looking for something that helps to store logs (like HDFS+HBase), calamaris as it seems only generates reports from locally stored web access logs. Splunk is probably overkill, I just need layer of storage and query engine.

Answer (score 2):

If you try to parse/collect logs in real-time, and do something about it then my recomendation is the following:

```
# tail --follow=name --retry /var/log/logfile.log | sendxmpp -i -u username -p password -j somejabberserver.com sendloglineto@somejabberserver.com
```

That would send each line in the log as it appears as XMPP message to the jabber user sendloglineto@somejabberserver.com. That jabber user would be one connected via client/software written by you (I prefer perl and Net::Jabber). You can program the client to do whatever you want it to do with each XMPP message (e.g. store in database). If you store it in CouchDB, you can use _changes API to track updates of particular database served by CouchDB.

Answer (score 1):

Eventhough, its old question, I am posting the answer with technical stack which are available now...

1. Data Ingestion : Apache Flume or Spark streaming  or Spring XD or Kafka
2. Data Storage and processing: HBASE(rawdata in staging table and aggregated data in final tables based on the requirements, based on the ranges of search ,can design rowkeys) + [SparkonHbase](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/12/new-in-cloudera-labs-sparkonhbase/)
3. Real time search : Hbase with solr indexes
4. Reporting(optional) : tableu or [Banana](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cqV5lPM2VVE)(open source)
5. Overall : [Lambda architecture](http://lambda-architecture.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Try Apache Kafka. It should be helpful for your case