# Aggregating and analyzing logs in real time from multiple servers

Tags: logging, analytics, distributed-computing

If I want to analyze billions of lines of logs in real time to figure out say, the top k user patterns and because of the humongous amount of data, there are multiple servers catering to the user requests and logging data on their respective machines, how should I go about doing it?

I am not looking for an open source implementation of the same which would help me in achieving the above task but an approach of going about aggregating logs from each machine (may not necessarily be required if a local aggregation is possible in the algorithm) and doing analysis on the full set to get the top few logs based on certain constraints.

What should be the data structures I should be operating with and what should be the approach on going about it? Please note that these logs are continuously getting generated and we are looking to update our results in real time.

Answer (score 0):

> What should be the data structures I should be operating with and what should be the approach on going about it?

MapReduce is traditionally used for such tasks, try [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/). [distributed `grep`](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Grep) is a school example, many others are using it for log management.

Comment: I completely understand the tools listed by you but I am not looking for existing tools but an approach of doing it on my own. Imagine me writing a tool for doing this task.

Comment: @AbhishekJain: MapReduce is a concept, Hadoop is an implementation. Study how MapReduce works, it's a great of how to implement distributed computations involving thousands of servers and TBs of data. You can't process that much data on one machine.

Comment: I agree with you on the fact that MapReduce is a concept but it is more suited for doing batch processing over a bulk of data and does not perform very well in real time environments. I have been using MapReduce and Hadoop for sometime but if I want to update my calculation every moment then it may not be a good choice as it has a strict batch workflow. What I want to do is a kind of incremental processing based on the events coming in real time. I know Storm by Twitter maybe a good case study of doing this but I want a brief approach of doing it right away (time constraint :( )

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/6484592/760401
I must say that I have never done it for such big amount of data, BUT :), both Jabber/XMPP and CouchDB are well known for their scaling capabilities.